# Linq OrderBy does not sort a List<T>. How do I sort the list?

Tags: c#, linq

Having issues with the OrderBy clause not having any impact on the sort. I have walked through this in the debugger and insuring this is a case that the sort line of the code is being hit and reviewing the results after it the order by has not been applied.

```
public static IEnumerable<DDLOptions<TValueType>> GetDDLOptionsViewModel<TClass, TValueType>(
            IEnumerable<TClass> list, 
            Func<TClass, TValueType> value, 
            Func<TClass, string> displayText,
            bool sort = true
        )
        {
            List<DDLOptions<TValueType>> ddlOptions;

            ddlOptions = list.Select(
                l => new DDLOptions<TValueType>
                        {
                            Value = value(l),
                            DisplayText = displayText(l)
                        }
                    ).ToList();  <========== Works if I put the Order By here.

            if (sort)
            {
                ddlOptions.OrderBy(l => l.DisplayText); <===== Does NOT work here.
            }

            return ddlOptions;
        }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`OrderBy` *returns* a query that would perform the ordering: it does not modify the original list (whereas something like `List<T>.Sort` would modify the original)

Instead try something like:

```
ddlOptions = ddlOptions.OrderBy(l => l.DisplayText).ToList();
```

You might want to play around with the type of `ddlOptions` or where/how you return the data as we're doing an extra `ToList` than probably necessary, but that's probably a minor/non-issue for this case anyway.

Note that the same applies to other LINQ functions like GroupBy, Distinct, Concat - all return results rather than modifying the source collection.

Comment: The easiest would be to just move `.ToList()` to the `return` statement.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens Probably, the only thing is as `ddlOptions` is defined, you wouldn't be able to reassign it: `OrderBy` returns an `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` not a `List<T>`. That's why I'm saying Chad might have to tweak the types or return logic.

Comment: True, but that should be an easy fix. `var` could be useful here as well.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens It would as long as Chad doesn't use the initial `ToList` or add any additional Linq that doesn't return `IEnumerable<DDLOptions<TValueType>>` explicitly. Personally, I'd probably favour just returning right in the if block and avoid type/IEnumerable reassignment in this case. But like you said, all this is pretty trivial/easy and up to Chad.

Comment: Yes, I delay the ToList to be called by the calling methods. Thank you all for the help! Everyone provided similar answers, but this one was technically correct because I was initially defining ddlOptions as a list (List<DDLOptions<TValueType>> ddlOptions). In the end I just made it an IEnumerable and did not call ToList as it is called in the calling method.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
if (sort)
{
    ddlOptions = ddlOptions.OrderBy(l => l.DisplayText); <===== Should work now.
}
```

Comment: It would be better if the `.ToList()` call was moved to the `return` statement so that the unordered list is not calculated.

Comment: @Venson Chad would have to redefine `ddlOptions` to something like `IEnumerable<DDLOptions<TValueType>>` for this assignment to work.

Comment: Don't seems so, If i am not Completely Wrong, this dos not matter because T is still the same just this List Interface is changed, and the Data should not take care of it.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, you need to assign the result of `OrderBy` to something as it doesn't mutate the sequence it acts on.  It's easiest to make `ddlOptions` an `IEnumerable` instead of a `List`, so that you can assign the result to that.  The `ToList` call on the select is also not needed:

```
public static IEnumerable<DDLOptions<TValueType>> GetDDLOptionsViewModel<TClass, TValueType>(
        IEnumerable<TClass> list,
        Func<TClass, TValueType> value,
        Func<TClass, string> displayText,
        bool sort = true
    )
{
    IEnumerable<DDLOptions<TValueType>> ddlOptions;

    ddlOptions = list.Select(
        l => new DDLOptions<TValueType>
                {
                    Value = value(l),
                    DisplayText = displayText(l)
                }
            );

    if (sort)
    {
        ddlOptions = ddlOptions.OrderBy(l => l.DisplayText);
    }

    return ddlOptions;
}
```

Note that this version of the method will use deferred execution, and so won't actually perform the Select/OrderBy until the sequence is iterated.  If you don't want to do that, you can add `ToList` on the `return` line.

Answer (score 1):

You need to type:

```
ddlOptions = ddlOptions.OrderBy(l => l.DisplayText);
```

Comment: I'm an idiot...of course...I forgot to assign it to itself. Thanks Soner! I did not have to call the ToList on it for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

`OrderBy` doesn't sort a `List<T>` or any other `IEnumerable<T>`. It produces a new, sorted `IEnumerable<T>`. So calling `ddlOptions.OrderBy(...)` doesn't modify `ddlOptions`.

If you have a `List<T>` and wish to sort it, you can use the [`Sort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Sort_System_Comparison__0__) method - in particular the overload that takes a `Comparison<T>` as a parameter. This actually sorts the list instead of returning a new `IEnumerable`.

[`Comparison<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.comparison-1) is a delegate representing a function that takes two of `T` and returns a negative number if the first is "less" than the second, a positive number if the first is "greater" than the second, and zero if one isn't sorted before or after the other.

In this case you don't have to remember that. Instead, you can just do this:

```
ddlOptions.Sort((x, y) => string.CompareOrdinal(x.DisplayText, y.DisplayText));
```

You're passing in a function that takes two items in the list and returns the comparison result of their `DisplayText` properties, which will be negative, 0, or positive.

Sometimes we use `OrderBy` *because* it doesn't modify the original list. But if modifying the list *is* what we want then we can use `Sort`.