# Linq statement OrderBy on DataRow collection not working

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following business entities and I want to apply LINQ on this.

```
public class DTPackage
{

    private int _packageID;

    private DTContract _flightComponent;
    private HotelAvailability.HotelCollectionRow _hotelComponent;
    .........
    #region Public Properties
}

public partial class HotelCollectionRow : global::System.Data.DataRow 
{

    private global::System.Data.DataColumn columnSortByEngine;
    private global::System.Data.DataColumn columnDistanceFromLocation;
    private global::System.Data.DataColumn columnSortByDistanceFromLocationGroup;
    private global::System.Data.DataColumn columnIsCommissionBased;
    private global::System.Data.DataColumn columnSortByRank;
    private global::System.Data.DataColumn columnSortByInternalRating;
}
```

I have written following query but it's not working.

My Query

```
 List<DTPackage> filterPackageList = null;
 var query = filterPackageList.AsEnumerable()
             .OrderByDescending(m => m.HotelComponent.DistanceFromLocation);
```

**filterPackageList  is full of data.**

Comment: how do you want to get results from null? FilterPackageList is null, am I right?

Comment: Umm....you set filterPackageList to null, and then you try to query on it. Not sure why it's not working is a surprise? :)

Comment: @wudzik:filterPackageList  is full with data.just for clarity I have removed the extra code

Comment: Please show that extra code !!!

Comment: @muski - please put the extra code back in, as chances are it might something in that extra code that's causing the problem.

Comment: @Guys.I am not getting any exception.The only problem is that order by is not applying on the collection

Comment: Because orderby does not affect list look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14403520/1714342

Comment: What type is DistanceFromLocation ? Is it a c# type ? If not, you have to tell the compiler how to compare values of this type, providing a DistanceFromLocationComparer (inheriting Comparer)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should try the below solution

```
var query = filterPackageList.AsEnumerable()
           .OrderByDescending(m => m.HotelComponent.DistanceFromLocation).ToList();
```

Comment: Then try
     var query = filterPackageList.OrderByDescending(m => m.HotelComponent.DistanceFromLocation).ToList();